# pass a file to command prompt by OpenWith dropdown menu

Tags: batch-file, cmd, qr-code, open-with

Well, There is an application called QRCP which can share files through LAN by Qr Code.
It uses a command in cmd to share the file:

[image: qrcp help]

I want to add this to SendTo dropdown menu, but the problem is I can't pass it the file that I want to share.

I need something like this:

[image: shortcut]

Which I could pass the file location with `%1`
and the final command should be like 
`qrcp send "D:\Program Files\file.exe"`

But it seems it's not how it works!

Comment: And how about create a shortcut on `SendTo` Folder ?

Comment: ..like [this](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-add-folders-to-send-to-menu-in-windows-10/#:~:text=Customize%20the%20Send%20to%20menu%20in%20Windows%2010,program%20shortcut%20on%20your%20desktop.)

Comment: The information you've shown, states that the command must be ```qrcp [command]```, or ```qrcp [flags]```. However you seem to be trying to use ```qrcp [file]```.

Comment: @Hackoo It just opens qrcp without any other arguments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that I tried on my side.

This batch file can create a shortcut on `SendTo` Folder and may be can do the trick for you too , just change the path of QRCP on your side :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title QRCP Batch File
REM Create a shortcut on SendTo Folder
REM "Call :CreateShortcut_SendTo" - This command calls the CreateShortcut_SendTo subroutine,
REM which creates a shortcut in the SendTo folder that can be used to easily execute the script.
Call :CreateShortcut_SendTo
REM This command sets the QRCP_Path variable to the location of the QRCP.exe file in the same directory as the batch file.
Set QRCP_Path="%~dp0QRCP.exe"
Set FilePath=%1

If "%FilePath%" == "" (
    Color 0C & echo No File was passed throw this Program, Exiting ... & Timeout /T 5 /NoBreak>nul & Exit
)

%QRCP_Path% %1
echo File %1 passed to QRCP
Exit /B

::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:CreateShortcut_SendTo
Powershell -Command "If (Test-Path '%Appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\%~n0.lnk') { Remove-Item '%Appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\%~n0.lnk' }"
Powershell ^
"$s=(New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut('%Appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\%~n0.lnk'); ^
$s.TargetPath='%~dpnx0'; ^
$s.WorkingDirectory='%~dp0'; ^
$s.IconLocation='%QRCP_Path%,0'; ^
$s.Save()"
Exit /B
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: With a little bit of editing, It worked. But it creates a shortcut of it's own bat file, not the one I passed with send to!

Comment: Of course and this what should be to do when you pass any file to the shortcut it will work what you want !

Comment: but this shortcut is created in Send To folder, not in the directory we are working with!

Comment: When you right-click over a file and send to the shortcut it will execute the batch file with the file passed as argument, just try it and tell me the result ?